# 7 Wonders: Do board resources (brown and gray) count for VPs when counting guild and commerce points?

Tags: 7-wonders

Three guilds (Workers, Shipowners, Craftsmens) award VPs for resource cards. Also some commerce cards (e.g., Haven) award coins and VPs for resource cards. Do you include Board resources in the count, or only cards? The instructions say "cards," but I'm making sure they are specifically restricting this, and not using the term more broadly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The guilds in question specifically award points for cards.

> Workers Guild: 1 victory point for each brown card present in the neighboring cities.
>
> Shipowners Guild: 1 victory point for each brown, gray and purple card in your city. *Clarification: the Shipowners Guild counts towards this total.*
>
> Craftmans Guild: 2 victory points for each gray card present in the neighboring cities.

And the last sentence in the base game Rulebook makes it clear this only refers to actual cards. [Emphasis added]

> *Clarification: Resources produced by boards **are NOT considered as cards** (Vineyard, Bazaar, Guilds, ...).*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm constantly amazed by the organization of rulebooks. Why isn't this stated at the Boards section, too?

Comment: this clarification was not provided in the polish rulebook, good to know